# How to start recovery from Recovery Partition on a ASUS A6000?

Tags: laptop, system-recovery

I can't find the manual that came with my ASUS A6000.

What was the key combination on boot to start the recovery process?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Press F9 on booting up (right after you power on and see the ASUS logo), you should now be able to access system recovery. (This is the sys-recovery combi on my ASUS.)

This is only if you have left intact your system recovery partition. If you have formatted or deleted that partition, you will have to get the recovery cds.