# Re-installing Windows 7 on Asus

Tags: windows-7, laptop, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start recovery from recovery partition on a Asus A6000 ?](https://superuser.com/questions/38332/how-to-start-recovery-from-recovery-partition-on-a-asus-a6000)

My laptop came with Windows 7 installed already. I need to re-install it however there were no disks and in fact the computer doesn't have a DVD drive anyway.

There is a folder on the pc called "C:\eSupport" however this doesn't appear to contain Windows installation just a few drivers etc. What should I do?

Comment: Possible Duplicate....http://superuser.com/questions/38332/how-to-start-recovery-from-recovery-partition-on-a-asus-a6000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing F9 at the boot splash screen should launch recovery.

[How to start recovery from recovery partition on a Asus A6000?](https://superuser.com/questions/38332/how-to-start-recovery-from-recovery-partition-on-a-asus-a6000)

http://asusforum.com/showthread.php?t=1542
.

Comment: When it was new there were a lot of extra programs installed that I did not need. I was hoping to do a clean installation of the operating system without any asus 'extras'?

Comment: Microsoft has a utility to copy a W7 install disc to a flash drive for installation via USB, you would need a W7 ISO of the install disc...http://store.microsoft.com/help/iso-tool

Comment: W7 ISO files here...http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/04/28/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any "additional features" you'd have to install from a flash drive. Check if your computer supports booting from a USB device.

Now you have to obtain a Windows 7 ISO, up to you is how to get it.

[This guide](http://www.blogsdna.com/2016/how-to-install-windows-7-from-usb-drive-without-windows-7-iso-dvd.htm) details how to install a fresh Windows 7 system from a flash drive.