# Corrupted NTFS partition

Tags: multi-boot, ntfs, chkdsk

I recently bought a new laptop (running like most Windows 10). Earlier today I attempted installing a linux distribuation as a dual boot, but I ran into another issue very early on.

Before attempting to resize the main 200G+ Windows partition (NTFS), I wanted to backup my Windows installation using `ntfsclone`. Which did not work : `NTFS signature is missing.`

I then attempted a `ntfsfix` and rebooted my computer into Windows, which expectedly ran the `chkdsk` utility, to no avail.

Running it manually from a command propmt does not work either :  `unable to determine volume version and state. chkdsk aborted`.

I have no idea what could have damaged my NTFS partition. All I did was list partitions using `fdisk`/`gdisk` from an Archlinux live USB, and attempt the clone. I have no easy way to recover Windows (I would need to send my freshly received laptop to Asus, as apparently they have a specific Windows image). I cannot run the Windows Reset either, nor restore an earlier backup, etc.

Extra details: 4 partitions were present (ESP, "Windows reserved", two data partions (one of which is the 200G+ partition at fault)

EDIT: `diskpart` shows the faulty partition as being "healthy" but having a "raw" fs

Comment: Does Asus ship with a recovery partition for windows?  This is old, but worth trying: https://superuser.com/questions/38332/how-to-start-recovery-from-recovery-partition-on-a-asus-a6000

Comment: not sure, but I think that's the recovery partition that's granting me access to the command prompt/reset options (althought they do not work)? f9 at least does nothing :/ thanks anyway!

Comment: what model ASUS is this?

Comment: its a Zenbook UX430

Comment: I recommend you reload windows 10 from a download.  once you sign in to your Microsoft account, it should restore your license.